# Styling last div inside a container

Tags: html, css

Firstly here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/zp44pb0a/).

I'm trying to style last div which is inside another div with class 'container'. 
':last-child' selector does not work.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="div-one">
    <h5> This is Div One </h5>
</div>
<div class="div-two">
    <h5> This is Div Two </h5>
</div>
<div class="div-three">
    <h5> This is Div Three </h5>
</div>
<div class="div-four">
    <h5> This is Div Four </h5>
</div>
```

I'm trying to style 'div-four'.

CSS code:

```
div.container:last-child{
  display: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`div.container:last-child` will select every children of `div.container` that is the last child of its parent, which in your case includes the `<h5>` elements.

Try this instead:

```
div.container div:last-child{
  display: none; 
}
```

```css
div.container div:last-child{
    display: none; 
}

h5{
    font-family: Montserrat;
    color: #49c8ff;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="div-one">
        <h5> This is Div One </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="div-two">
        <h5> This is Div Two </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="div-three">
        <h5> This is Div Three </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="div-four">
        <h5> This is Div Four </h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

The `last-child` selector basically takes the current selector and finds the last child of its parent. So in your case, `div.container:last-child` says "all the divs with the container class that are the last child of their parent." Well in your case the parent is `<body>` and the last child matching is the `<div class="container">` What you want is `div.container > *:last-child` which will find the last child of the `div.container`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 5):

You just need to change your

```
div.container:last-child {
    display: none; 
}
```

to

```
div.container div:last-child {
    display: none; 
}
```

This tells it to locate the last `div` that is located within the `div.container` instead of every `div` within the container.

Here is the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L6x9weLa/1).

Comment: @Evochrome thank you, didn't realize it wasn't updated. Updated link in the solution.